# Does an OFFLINE Database use space?

Tags: sql-server, storage, offline

I took my SQL Server Database `OFFLINE`. Is it still occupying the same space as when it was `ONLINE`?

Should I keep it `OFFLINE` or is it better to `BACKUP` the database and `DROP` it?

Comment: Having no idea what your actual goals are, the only answer is, “I don’t know.”

Comment: At my new work location, i have seen few databases as OFFLINE so just curious If it's occupying space if we are not going to use it so is it better to take backup and store somewhere .bak file so at least we can free up some space as it's taking few hundred GB of space?

Comment: Whether it’s better or not depends on why it’s offline. If I’m not wearing a sweatshirt should I throw it away? Depends on whether I plan to wear it again, whether I’ve outgrown it, it’s ripped/stained, etc.

Answer (score 3):

An OFFLINE database is indeed still occupying space on disk. You can verify this by finding the location of the database files with a quick peek at [`sys.master_files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql) and then navigating in windows explorer to the directory location.

```
select * 
from sys.master_files 
where database_id = db_id('my_offline_db');
```

If it's not bothering you, then there's no need to drop the database. You might run into some maintenance processes that don't play nice with an offline database, but it's a matter of preference whether you modify these processes to gracefully handle and offline database or you remove the offline db from your instance.

If you choose to drop the database to free up disk space, [you will need to remember to manually delete the files afterwards](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/02/dropping-offline-database-sql-server/). If you want to quickly browse some reasons why you might keep the offline database around, [this ServerFault question is a good read](https://serverfault.com/questions/201171/why-would-i-take-a-database-offline).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends upon why that database was taken offline in the first place.

Get a confirmation for the reasons of it's being taken offline followed by any company or vendor policy which needs db to be offline say for x days and then can be dropped entirely from the instance.

You can check from various scripts online though when it was taken offline. You can get an idea I'd that is sitting there for too long doing nothing but eating up unwanted space. So answer is more from your side of researching to do on that db being taken offline.

Comment: Thanks and I agreed with you completely. My concern was to verify that offline DB eating up unwanted space as if we are not going to use it so just take a backup, store somewhere else and drop the DBs.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I was looking online but didn't get exact when it was taken offline as some of has suggest to see log file and search "Off line marked" word but any system table stores info to find out exact or how long sitting offline?